# how to make selected row editable on click of edit button In angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I have a table with select and select all check box , i want to make the selected row editable on select and click of edit button.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor='let row of rowData'>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.email}}</td>
    <td>{{row.remark}}</td>
    <td>{{row.test1}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Test2}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Test3}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Test4}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Test5 }}</td>
    <td>{{row.Test6 }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a property to your `rowData`, such as `editable`.
Then layout your code like this:

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let row of rowData' [ngClass]="{ 'selected': row.selected }">
          <td class="text-center>
              <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="row.selected" />
          </td>
          <td>
             <input type="text" *ngIf="row.editable" [(ngModel)]="row.name" />
             <ng-container *ngIf="!row.editable">{{row.name}}</ng-container>
             <!-- You can use span or whatever instead of ng-container-->
          </td>
          <!-- Repeat for other cells -->      
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

For the select all part, I assume you have checkbox in the thead. It needs to have this code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll($event)" /></td>
```

Then in your component:

```
    selectAll(event) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            this.rowData = this.rowData.map((row) => {
               row.selected = true;
               return row;
            });
        } else {
            this.rowData = this.rowData.map((row) => {
               row.selected = false;
               return row;
            });
        }
    }
```

Then you must have an edit button above table that takes all selected rows and makes them editable.

```
makeEditable() {
  this.rowData = this.rowData.map((row) => {
     if (row.selected) { row.editable = true; }
     else { row.editable = false; }
     return row;
  });
}
```

Call this on edit button click.

Comment: This is not working for select all, Mean i have a check box to select all rows.

Comment: @user1999324 You need to add a button to enable switching editable on or off. This has nothing to do with selection.

Comment: @user1999324 I don't understand. The code I wrote enables you to click on the checkbox to make a row editable. If you write the same code like the second td with ngIfs, it will make your whole row editable. What does it have to do with selecting all? For selecting you need to have another property such as selected.

Comment: Yes, that is my other part of question, how to perform select all

Comment: And my requirement is , once we select the row and then click on edit button , then only row should become editable

Comment: makeEditable() {
  this.rowData--(this line is throwing error) = this.rowData.map((row) => {
     if (row.selected) { row.editable = true; }
     else { row.editable = false; }
  });
}
Type 'void[]' is not assignable to typ
e '{ name: string; email: string; remark: string; test1: string; Test2: string; Test3: string; Test4..

Comment: Changed this.rowData = this.rowData.map((row) => {
 to
let rowData = this.rowData.map((row) => {

Comment: But one big prob is there with this code, that is select all will select all the row but once we select all the row one by one  select all check box is not getting checked.

Comment: @user1999324 I have given you the idea, you should expand on it further. You need to listen to the checkbox change event on your single checkboxes, and check if every one of rowData is checked. The you can either use a template variable or a flag to mark your checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let row of rowData; let i = index'> 
    <tr *ngIf="selected === i">
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.name"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.email"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.remark"></td>

      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.test1"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.test2"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.test3"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.test4"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.test5"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.test6"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngIf="selected !== i" (click)="selected = i">
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <td>{{row.email}}</td>
      <td>{{row.remark}}</td>

      <td>{{row.test1}}</td>
      <td>{{row.Test2}}</td>
      <td>{{row.Test3}}</td>
      <td>{{row.Test4}}</td>
      <td>{{row.Test5 }}</td>
      <td>{{row.Test6 }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Comment: "not working" isn't really information. What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? Do you get an error message? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a new component, like this, and write all logic there, for example (very fast code writing):

```
    <span [hidden]="!isDisplay" (click)="beginEdit(editText)">
        {{ text }}
    </span>
    <span [hidden]="isDisplay">
        <input #editText type="text" [value]="text">
    </span>


export class InlineEditComponent {
    @Input() public text: any;
    @Output() public edit = new EventEmitter<string>();

    public isDisplay = true;

    constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('document:click', [ '$event.target' ])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        if (!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(targetElement)) {
            this.isDisplay = true;
        }
    }

    public beginEdit(el: HTMLElement): void {
        this.isDisplay = false;
        setTimeout(() => {
            el.focus();
        }, 100);
    }

    public editDone(newText: any): void {
        this.isDisplay = true;
        this.edit.emit(newText);
    }
}
```

then use it in your table

Comment: Please provide the plunker example for table.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks for asking and @Günter Zöchbauer for answering your answer gave me a hint!

So, my solution would be to create a new key in your iterating object (row).
With input tag disabled and some css for that, or another approach would be adding two elements with *ngIf.

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor='let row of rowData'>
<td class="text-center">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkboxVal" (change)="checkboxChangeHandler(row)"/>
</td>
<td><input type="text" [disabled]="row.isEditable" [value]="row.name"/> 
</td>
<td>
<ng-container *ngIf="!row.isEditable">{{row.email}}</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="row.isEditable"><input type="text" [value]="row.email"/></ng-container>
</td>
<td>{{row.remark}}</td>
<td>{{row.test1}}</td>
<td>{{row.Test2}}</td>
<td>{{row.Test3}}</td>
<td>{{row.Test4}}</td>
<td>{{row.Test5 }}</td>
<td>{{row.Test6 }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Logic Js/Ts:

```
checkboxChangeHandler(row: any) {
    if (checkboxVal) {
         row.isEditable = true;
    }else {
         row.isEditable = false;
    }
    // or simply change it like this -> row.isEditable = !row.isEditable;
}
```

CSS if you are using the Input with the disabled approach:

```
input:disabled {
   background-color: transparent; // based on your preference!
   border: none;
}
```