# How to change text fields to input element in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

[My Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66zFk.jpg)

I wanted to implement a single click edit button to change all my fields to input,
Here is my HTML

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="add-details">
    <span>LemonCandy, #78, IG Circle,</span>
    <span>JP Nagar Phase 1, Bangalore</span>
    <span>Karnataka, 560078</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="id-details">
    <span>info@lemoncanday.in</span>
    <span>skipper@lemoncanday.in</span>
    <span><a (click)="editDetails()" title="Edit Details">Edit Details</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
```

Comment: what have you tried ? There is no `<input>` in your code, and no JS code.

Comment: Use `*ngIf="..."` to show either normal text or alternatively an `<input>`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793089/how-to-make-selected-row-editable-on-click-of-edit-button-in-angular-4/45793334#45793334

Comment: I don't want it to use is this way i want , is an inline edit element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use input instead of span and disable it based on flag . If required do some CSS tweeks to change textbox view like span

```
<div class="col-md-3"><div class="add-details"><input type="text" [disabled]={{typeflag}}>LemonCandy, #78, IG Circle,</input><input type="text" [disabled]={{typeflag}}>JP Nagar Phase 1, Bangalore</input><input type="text" [disabled]={{typeflag}}>Karnataka, 560078</input></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><div class="id-details">
<input type="text" [disabled]={{typeflag}}>info@lemoncanday.in</input><input type="text" [disabled]={{typeflag}}>skipper@lemoncanday.in</input><input type="text" [disabled]={{typeflag}}><a (click)="editDetails()" title="Edit Details">Edit Details</a></input></div>
```